# Border-radius not completely working on simple horizontal navigation buttons…

Tags: css

Sorry for another newbie question but for the life of me I can't figure out How to get rid of the rectangular border that superimposes Each rounded navigation Button on this very simple navigation menu. If you magnify, you can see what I'm talking about or look down below at the pictures I posted. [Link to what it looks like on the web](http://www.spineresearcher.org/)

I would greatly appreciate somebody helping me out, and thank you so much in advance. I would also appreciate any comments on my layout, as I am just learning how to do this.

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
      <h1> Welcome to ChirogGeek.com!</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="navMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../home.html">Introduction</a></li><li><a href="#">Methods</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Discussion</a></li>                 
        <li><a href="#">Conclusion</a></li>    
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </div> <!--close wrapper -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  float: 0;
}

body {
  background-color:#CFF;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color:#FF9;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

#header {
  float:left;
  background-color:#39C;
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:  center;
  line-height:100px;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive
}

#navMenu {
  float:left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#006;
}

#navMenu ul {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#navMenu li {
  margin-right: 5px;
  float: left;
  background: #999;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navMenu a {
  display: block;
  height: 25px; width: 150px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px #FFF solid;
  background-color: #666;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  text-align: center;
}


/*link colors*/

#navMenu a:visited {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
}

#navMenu li:hover > a {
  background-color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
}

#navMenu a:hover {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
}

#navMenu a:active {
  color: #0F0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;
}
```

[image: Unwanted rectangular border beneath rounded corners]

[image: Here's what it looks like After removing the border rule]

Comment: Could you post a link? Do you want to get rid of the rounded edges or the border altogether? It seems like you maybe posted the html, but it actually rendered.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. I've posted an image of a button and you can see there is a faint gray rectangle that is showing up underneath the round-corner button. I would like to get rid of this rectangular background and have pure rounded buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a link to a codepen](http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/syfmF). All I did was delete the background on the list. There is no need to have a background set on the li and the anchor tag. That's why it is extending past the border: you would have to set a border-radius on both the li and the a. But all you really need to do is take the background off the li. You can see that it is commented out in the code. That is all I changed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That Deletion solved the problem, but created another. It knocked out the button Hover color.  If you can figure out how to restore the button color change (not the button text change, that still works) when hovered over, then the problem is solved :-) Any ideas?  Edit: I just added the border-radius command as you suggested to the li, and now everything is working fine.  Was there a better way to do this?

Comment: I just updated the pen. All you have to do is delete the hover on <li>: only use the :hover for the <a> element. And instead of using background: transparent, just set it to the color you want, i.e., #999. You can see it all on the pen. (Just saw your edit. The pen is probably a better way to do it. There is no reason for it to be so complicated. You really only need to target the <a> instead of both the <li> and the <a>, if that makes sense.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for taking the time to show me how to do that correctly; it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I copied your code and what I get is a border outside the fill region of the button.
This will happen because you specify a "white" border in the css.

You can delete the [border: 1px #FFF solid;] in your css code and leave the [border-radius: 5px;] as it is. The extra border will be gone.

Comment: Thank you. But all this did was take away the white border and you can still see the rectangular border beneath the rounded button. A post a picture of what mine looks like.

Comment: Oh, I see! It looks like you have a light-gray background color somehow behind those buttons. Do you have another CSS file to check that? If you do, try to look for a background color in the "wrapper" holding those buttons. I will check again and comment if I find something else.

Comment: Ok! Delete the [background: #999;] from the #navMenu li (or set it transparent). Did that works?

Comment: That solves the problem, but creates another. It knocked out the button Hover color.  If you can figure out how to restore the button color change (not the button text, that still works) when hovered over, then the problem is solved :-)

Comment: Edit: I just added the border-radius code to the li, and that fixed the problem. Was there a better way to do this, or will this be okay?

Comment: Yes, every <li> will have the same property inside the Menu and each button will have the same property so yes, that would be ok! :)

Answer (score 0):

. . I have a sample code that you built. I put an image in the link below. Look. And the code looks like this :

http://payaupload.ir/up/92/12/1393784266.jpg

HTML :

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
      <h1> Welcome to ChirogGeek.com!</h1>
    </div>
<div id="navMenu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../home.html">Introduction</a></li><li><a href="#">Methods</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Discussion</a></li>                 
    <li><a href="#">Conclusion</a></li>    
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div> <!--close wrapper -->
</body>
```

CSS :

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  float: 0;
}
body {
  background-color:#CFF;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
}
#wrapper {
  background-color:#FF9;
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
}

#header {
  float:left;
  background-color:#39C;
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  text-align:  center;
  line-height:100px;
  font-family:"Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px 30px 0 0;
}
#navMenu {
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#2760C9;
}
#navMenu ul {
    margin:0;
}
#navMenu ul li {
    float:left;
    padding: 35px 10px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
}
#navMenu ul li a {
    color:#070;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 6px;
    background-color:#7EDAED;
    border-radius: 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
}
#navMenu ul li a:hover {
    color:#005B00;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color:#BAEBF5;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't understand why it is showing up different; although, I am testing it via Dreamweaver CS5's Web preview button.I have posted a couple of images of what I'm getting. I will upload it to my Go Daddy account and see what it looks like for real. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. I uploaded it to my Go Daddy account and viewed it for real and it still the same. [link]http://www.SpineResearcher.org [/link]